# netplan+networkd portable/usb setup

Tags: usb, netplan, systemd-networkd

I have a number of bootable USB drives with Ubuntu 18.04 which had been upgraded from past versions of Ubuntu. Now I am looking for the most proper and concise config for netplan to express a rule like : for the first onboard/pci wired Ethernet on the booted host (regardless of its interface name), configure it through DHCP or through Avahi autoipd as a fallback.

I have already replaced cron with systemd-cron, and removed rsyslog in favor of systemd-journald; now it's turn to remove ifupdown+resolvconf+isc-dhcp-client in favor of netplan+systemd-networkd

Thanks in advance for your responses.

---

(update from 2020-12-25)
I learned it could be done even without netplan.
Create networkd configs `/etc/systemd/network/en.network` with content like

```
[Match]  
Name=en*  
[Network]  
DHCP=ipv4
```

and `/etc/systemd/network/wl.network` with content like

```
[Match]
Name=wl*
[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
```

then do `systemctl enable systemd-networkd`, and after next reboot you will have any your en* interface configurable by networkd built-in dhcp client.
What is left to be found out, is how to use the same config of `wpa_supplicant` when you have different wl* interface names when booting on different hardware.