# Can I enable dhcp4 on all interfaces globally without knowing the interface names with netplan and networkd?

Tags: networking, netplan, systemd-networkd

Can I enable DHCP4on all interfaces globally without knowing the interface names with netplan?
I might add any USB connected ethernet NIC, and I just want any of them to get the network config via DHCP4.
I know it works with NetworkManager. But I would rather use the networkd renderer.

Comment: Are you running a Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server? Is there a reason to choose netplan?

Comment: I am running a minimal installation of Ubuntu Desktop. No GUI for networking is needed. There's no specific reason to use netplan. However I don't want to run the NetworkManager service and use networkd instead.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to enable dhcp4 without knowing device names... unless you can find where the default of dhcp4=false is set, and then change it to =true.

Comment: you may want to have a look at my solution to this problem, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069033/netplannetworkd-portable-usb-setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to enable wifi on an interface without knowing the exact interface name by using the `match` syntax:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    alleths:
      match:
        name: en*
      dhcp4: true
```

Be sure to avoid any settings that would collide between multiple interfaces (and do not use `set-name`).

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to do an inverse match, so I can match all interfaces except `lo`?

Comment: an inverse match is not supported, but since all ethernet devices will be named either en* or eth* by default, you can either duplicate the section with two different match rules, or generalize the match to `name: e*`, to ensure it covers all ethernet devices.